# R data export to Excel with additional columns

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, export

I'm trying to export data into excel in 5 sections each separated by an empty column between them.

My data frame has 48 columns. I'm failing with last separation where empty column doesn't appear between Section 4 & 5.

My Code:

```
Section1     <- DataFrame[,1:7]
Section2     <- DataFrame[,8:12]
Section3     <- DataFrame[,13:30]
Section4     <- DataFrame[,31:35]
Section5     <- DataFrame[,36:48]

writeData(wb, sheet = 1, Section1, rowNames = FALSE, colNames = TRUE, keepNA = FALSE)
writeData(wb, sheet = 1, Section2, rowNames = FALSE, colNames = TRUE, keepNA = FALSE, startCol = 9)
writeData(wb, sheet = 1, Section3, rowNames = FALSE, colNames = TRUE, keepNA = FALSE, startCol = 15)
writeData(wb, sheet = 1, Section4, rowNames = FALSE, colNames = TRUE, keepNA = FALSE, startCol = 34)
writeData(wb, sheet = 1, Section5, rowNames = FALSE, colNames = TRUE, keepNA = FALSE, startCol = 39)

saveWorkbook(wb, "/View.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Could you please indicate where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: Hello Jakub and welcome to SE. Could you add some sample data to your question? Providing a reproducible example greatly increases the chances that you get a correct and complete answer.

This being said, if my understanding of your question is correct, I'd simply start at column 40 rather than 39: `writeData(wb, sheet = 1, Section5, rowNames = FALSE, colNames = TRUE, keepNA = FALSE, startCol = 40)`

Comment: @byouness, Hi and thanks for warm welcoming.
Unfortunately I can't provide a data example now. To your point - I've tried that but the column # 39 is being populated with the same values as the #40.

Comment: @byouness, Problem solved. I've provided a startColumn variable for the Section1 and it started to work. Thanks for support!

Comment: Great. Please post an answer to your question with what you did so that other people can benefit from it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned the answer is to indicate the startCol vector in the first argument.

```
Section1     <- DataFrame[,1:7]
Section2     <- DataFrame[,8:12]
Section3     <- DataFrame[,13:30]
Section4     <- DataFrame[,31:35]
Section5     <- DataFrame[,36:48]

writeData(wb, sheet = 1, Section1, rowNames = FALSE, colNames = TRUE, keepNA = FALSE, startCol = 1)
writeData(wb, sheet = 1, Section2, rowNames = FALSE, colNames = TRUE, keepNA = FALSE, startCol = 9)
writeData(wb, sheet = 1, Section3, rowNames = FALSE, colNames = TRUE, keepNA = FALSE, startCol = 15)
writeData(wb, sheet = 1, Section4, rowNames = FALSE, colNames = TRUE, keepNA = FALSE, startCol = 34)
writeData(wb, sheet = 1, Section5, rowNames = FALSE, colNames = TRUE, keepNA = FALSE, startCol = 39)
```

Additionally, I highly recommend dividing the whole data frame into sections to improve the readability of the code as well as any future changes to it.